# Format decimal value in database in where clause

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5.1

I want to get data from database but the format of values that are compared do not tally.

The numbers in database are saved in weird format - sometimes are rounded and some of those are decimals (10, 14, 15, 12.44, 16.10, etc.)

In array I have values rounded on 2 decimals though.

I want to get data from database like so:

```
$foundPayments = $this>paymentsRepo>newQuery()>whereRaw("CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),payments.amount) = :payments", ['payments' => $payments]);
```

Althought, I end up with an error like this: `Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near ","`

I am not sure if the code works in `laravel 5.1` with sending params like I do but thats not really what I do care for in that - the same error apperars even when I do not use variable.

EDIT:

I am using Postgres.

Comment: Have you tried to make MySQL query first that works and converts column value properly? Also MySQL's `convert` takes parameters in [different order as it appears](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_convert.asp).

Comment: I'm sorry I do not use MySQL but Postgres I did not specify that. I will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the syntax that you are using for the convert function is wrong. You should first pass the value then the type to which you are converting to.
But please try the cast function, I think that it should give you the expected result.

```
$foundPayments = $this->paymentsRepo->newQuery()
    ->whereRaw("CAST(payments.amount as DECIMAL(10,2)) = :payments", 
              ['payments' => $payments]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much I will test it but it looks good. The `CAST` works but the parameter does not - I get : `invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters`

Comment: @Epsilon47 well, I did not paid much attention to your `:payments`. What should be there? What you should be doing actually is `select CAST(amount as DECIMAL(10,2)) from payments;`, if `$payments` contains an array you are trying to convert the values from, this won't work.

Comment: oh no, it is just a single value, like (10,00) I am sorry, the variable name isnt' very good

Comment: I just noticed you are using postgres, I don't think that in postgres there is a decimal function, you should try:
`ROUND(payments.amount, 2) = :payments`. The way you pass the named parameter is correct I think.